# How to modify the AppointmentItem.Parent object

Tags: outlook, vsto, office-interop

I need to set a UserProperty on a master of a recurring Appointment, from an appointment instance.

The scenario is:
a. user opens an instance of a recurring meeting/appointment.
b. my program sets a UserProperty on the master of the appointment series

Getting the master appointment is easy with the Parent property, however it is read-only.

How can I get a modify-able reference to the master appointment?

The code I want to execute is along these lines

```
Outlook.AppointmentItem masterAppointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)(currentAppointment.Parent);
masterAppointment.ItemProperties.Add("xxx", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
masterAppointment.ItemProperties["xxx"].Value = aStringValue;
masterAppointment.Save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think that AppointmentItem.Parent returns a read-only AppointmentItem?
Do you get an error when you call Save?
If you need to add a custom property, use AppointmentItem.UserProperties.Add.

Comment: I didnt notice it at first, but the MSDN documentation says it's a read-only property on AppointmentItem.  When I try to add a user proprety on the parent item I get an exception:

Comment: But you're right - I was getting an exception in that block of code and I thought what was causing it, but it wasn't.

Comment: It is read-only in a sense that you cannot set set it: e.g. (AppointmentItem.Parent = SomeOtherFolder) will not work. But the object returned from the Parent property is editable unless the current user has read-only access to the folder where the appointment resides. What is the exact error that you are getting?